# Кавычки в C и C++

Tags: c++, c

Собственно хочу понять механизм того что происходит с компилятором в C и C++ если объявить символ вот так 'a' и вот так "a".
Весь смысл изложен в этой программе

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("This is %s\n", (sizeof('a') == sizeof(char)) ? "C++" : "C");
    return 0;
}
```

в принципе понятно что происходит по факту, но не всовсем понятно как это работает изнутри.

Comment: Ничего не понятно. В этой программе нет никакой завязки на различие между `'a'` и `"a"`. Какой "весь смысл" вы имеете в виду? О чем вопрос? Об `'a'` и `"a"`? Или о программе?

Comment: Разница в том что в Си 'a' приведётся к int и будет равно 4 (на 32 битной платформе) , т.е если собрать код на чистом си то выражение тернарного оператора ? будет неверно, в Плюсах же символ будет char и соотвестенно выражение будет верно. Можно увидет это тут https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_c_compiler собрав в разных режимах  (C или C++)

Comment: Еще раз: размер типа `int` может быть равен чему угодно, даже на 32-битной платформе. Это во-первых. Во-вторых, по прежнему не ясно, почему в вашем вопросе упоминается `"a"`. При чем здесь `"a"`?

Comment: Надежный способ отличить С от С++ это `#ifdef __cplusplus`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Пример в коде - классический пример различия между с и с++. В с++ символ в кавычках - это char. И размер его - 1. В си все приводится к int  и размер 4.

А различие между одинарными и двойными кавычками просто - в одинарных - символ, в двойных - строка (массив char).

Самое интересное, что об этом даже в [википедии](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B8_(%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)#%D0%A1%D0%B8_%D0%B8_C++) написано:)

И почитать у [Alena cpp](http://alenacpp.blogspot.com/2009/03/sizeofa.html).

Comment: Формально никто не запрещает `sizeof(int) == sizeof(char) == 1`. Более того, такие платформы существуют в реальности (компиляторы для TI контроллеров). Поэтому в общем случае отличить С от С++ таким способом не получится.

Comment: @Croessmah: См. выше. В терминологии С и С++ "байт" - это `char`. В `char` может быть и 8, и 16, и 32, и 64 бита. Поэтому никакого нарушения требований языка в `sizeof(int) == sizeof(char) == 1` нет. На таких платформах, разумеется, `CHAR_BIT` должен быть не менее 16, чтобы удовлетворить требованиям диапазона `int`.

Comment: Хм, глянул стандарт C11, в отличие от C++, где литерал `'ё'` может и не компилироваться, в C такой литерал должен успешно компилироваться всегда (детально не изучал, могу быть не прав). И [компилируется](https://ideone.com/vEzATC).

Comment: @wololo, ideone тебя обманывает. У него исходник в utf-8 и получается вот примерно такая фигня: https://ideone.com/4L0bv2 & https://ideone.com/SKvHO5

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73368/discussion-on-answer-by-kovadim---c--c).

Answer (score 1):

В одинарных кавычках — символ, в двойных кавычках — строка.

Вам может показаться интересной данная статья [Типы данных в C](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%8B_%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85_%D0%B2_C)

Comment: В двойных кавычках не строка, а указатель на строку (char*). А если быть точным, то (const char*). И (const wchar_t*) - если L"Hello".

Comment: @kisssko в двойних кавычках не указатель куда-то там, а массив char'ов соответствующего размера, т.е. `"hello"` имеет тип не `const char*`, а `const char[6]`.

Comment: @kisssko, нет, в C++ выражение в двойных кавычках — это массив из `n` элементов типа `const char` — это требование стандарта языка. Другое дело, что строковый литерал, как и любой другой массив в C++, запросто может низводиться до указателя на его первый элемент. Однако, это происходит не всегда. [Пример для размышления](https://ideone.com/LWDEZq).

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73369/discussion-on-answer-by-hlib-derbenov---c--c).